# SwiftUI - How to activate TextField automatically when view loads?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, textfield

I have a TextField in a view that looks something like this:

```
@FocusState private var keyboardFocused: Bool

VStack {
  TextField("Name your item...", text: $itemName)
    .focused($keyboardFocused)
  
  ...
}
```

Now, this is all embedded in a view that loads when a button is pressed, like this:

```
Button(action: someAction, label: { ... })
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewIsPresented) {
  ViewWithTextField(...)
}
```

I want to make it so that when this view loads, the TextField is automatically activated/(focused?) and the keyboard pops up. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply set your `@FocusState` to `true` in `.onAppear` and wrap it in a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`. The delay is needed because the view has to be on screen before the `@FocusState` is changed or it won't work.

```
VStack {
  TextField("Name your item...", text: $itemName)
    .focused($keyboardFocused)
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            keyboardFocused = true
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: i should have mentioned that this view is presented with `.fullScreenCover`, which seemingly makes this method not work. do you know a workaround?

Comment: Post an actual [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I need to see exactly how it is implemented/

Comment: okay, I've edited the question to show the exact implementation.

Comment: Two things. First, please review the [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) link. We should be able to take your code and build it. Second, I want to call your attention to the second sentence in my answer: "The delay is needed because the view has to be on screen before the @FocusState is changed or it won't work." The code works fine. It just takes longer for the full screen cover to appear on screen. You need to adjust the delay time.